# HTML 5 geolocation POSITION UNAVAILABLE error in mobile

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

i am trying to get user current position in mobile web application 
my app work in all android telephone device except samsung galaksy s2 telephone device ..
it give errror  POSITION UNAVAILABLE error
this is [demo](http://f.hybridsoftware.net/KonuDetail.htm?q=1378)  link.you can view source 
this is code

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query1, handle_errors) ;
       function handle_errors(error) {
            switch (error.code) {
                    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("user did not share geolocation data");
                        break;
                    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("could not detect current position");
                        break;
                    case error.TIMEOUT: alert("retrieving position timed out");
                        break;
                    default: alert("unknown error");
                        break;
                }
            } 
       function handle_geolocation_query1(position) {



               $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
                     'id':'m_1',
                    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude),
                    'bounds': true,
                    'icon': 'http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geolocationmarker/images/gpsloc.png'
                }).click(function () {
           $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow',{ 'content': '<font color="#2a2a2a" size="4">Location </font><br/><font color="#4a4a4a">Your current location</font>' }, this);
                });
                 var map = $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'map');
                map.setZoom(14);
                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(41.01802007732287, 28.971880674362183));
                map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);



            }
```

edited:
i used phonegap to produce android apk file 
when i work this apk file application it give error POSITION UNAVAILABLE error  but when i call this page from web it works it does not give error  ... this is web [link](http://f.hybridsoftware.net/KonuDetail.htm?q=1365) and you can download apk from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hybridsoftware.istanbulluxguide)

Comment: Looks like your code is working as intended.

Comment: in browser it works...in many android telephone device it works..it just does not work on samsung galaksy s2 telephone device

Comment: Well it's working in the sense that the Geolocation service is returning you a [valid status (`POSITION_UNAVAILABLE`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#position_error_interface). Have you conclusively determined that your Samsung Galaxy SII isn't at fault? Try another Geolocation service and see if it works.

Comment: in my device in other my friend device it works..but in my customer samsung galaksy s2 it does not work...it give position_unvailable error...how can i fix this?closing gps in settings??

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine in browser but not in mobile.

On checking your source code it seems you're specifying the *sensor parameter as false*.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

You missed this while checking the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation).

> **Specifying the Sensor Parameter**
>
> Use of the Google Maps API requires that you indicate whether your
>   application is using a sensor (such as a GPS locator) to determine the
>   user's location. This is **especially important for mobile devices.**
>   Applications must pass a required sensor parameter to the  tag
>   when including the Maps API javascript code, indicating whether or not
>   your application is using a sensor device.
>
> ***Applications that determine the user's location via a sensor must pass
>   sensor=true when loading the Maps API JavaScript.***

Hope you understand.

Comment: i will try this thank you but ....in browser it works...in many android telephone device it works..it just does not work on samsung galaksy s2 telephone device...  is this parameter is just for samsung galaksy s2 device?

Comment: @user1688401 I think no.  Google maps may not have for individual device.  Check the GPS of that particular device.  Maybe there lying the issue.

Comment: i tried sensor=true but it still does not work..it gives  error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE   error

Comment: This answer solved the problem for me, I have a Cordova project running on a Genymotion VM.

Comment: this totally fixed the issue for me. what I want to know if why changing a setting in the google maps api has any affect on the browsers built in location api. This shouldn't make any difference since the location isnt coming from google.

Comment: The sensor parameter on initialising Google Maps is not longer required: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation

Answer (score 0):

On my device, I had my settings for Location mode set to "Device only".
In this case, I wasn't able to get a good connection of location and hence get Position Unavailable.
I change my Settings > Location > Mode  and change it to High Accuracy.
It took me a lot of days to get this problem to work unknowingly that the problem is in the device itself. I did my best capability to fix the codes, and even traced back to the plugin's code.
Please respect my post. Some people might have this problem as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with Messenger webview, the location for Messenger was denied in phone settings so the error was resolved after allowing the location sharing for the Messenger app.